# Leastsq does not fit the given data

Tags: python, sympy, mathematical-optimization, least-squares

I am trying to fit a bass model through some collected data by using a least squares fit. Although my code does not give an error, the parameter values given by leastsq does not match my data at all. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue?
I am pretty sure the problem lies within the leastsq function because the value of varfinal[0] is way to low. I have tried the code on other data sets and there it works just fine...
The code I'm using is given below:

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#time intervals
t = np.arange(1960,2021,1)
t0 = np.arange(0, len(t),1)
#t= [1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]

#xlabels
x = np.arange(1960,2080,20)
x_len = len(np.arange(1960,2100,1))
#places of xlabels
x0 = np.arange(0,x_len,20)

# papers vector
#keywords AND
patents=np.array([0,2,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,2,8,2,1,7,8,24,33,30,33,36,78,86,96,67,82,107,90,123,160,116,177,143,246,271,552,736,1137,1857,2681,3329,4044,5064,6318,6928,8843,9531,13560,14665,16801,19945,21421,25584,34608,43150,49742,53006,56061,61777,66665,64216,60540])
# cumulatice papers
cum_patents=np.cumsum(patents)+3
# initial variables(M, P & Q)
vars = [600000, 0.03,0.38]

# residual (error) function
def residual(vars, t, papers):
    M = vars[0]
    P = vars[1]
    Q = vars[2]
    Bass = M * (((P+Q)**2/P)*np.exp(-(P+Q)*t))/(1+(Q/P)*np.exp(-(P+Q)*t))**2 
    return (Bass - (papers))
                 
# non linear least square fitting
varfinal,success = leastsq(residual, vars, args=(t0, patents))

# estimated coefficients
m = varfinal[0]
p = varfinal[1]
q = varfinal[2]


print(varfinal)
#time interpolation
tp=(np.linspace(1.0, 110.0, num=100))
cofactor= np.exp(-(p+q) * tp)

# Cumulative sales (cdf)
patents_cdf= m*(1-cofactor)/(1+(q/p)*cofactor)
plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.plot(tp, patents_cdf,"r")
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(t0,cum_patents)
plt.title('Total patent applicants')
plt.legend(['Fit', 'True'])
plt.ylabel("Cumulative patent applicants")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.xticks(x0,x)
plt.savefig("lib_number_of_patents_bass_fit.png")
plt.show()
```

The output for the variables is:

```
[24.24333383  0.07548748 -0.32937682]
```

[True data vs leastsq fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCFYR.png)

Comment: I haven't got a reason for you, but it seems good if you use `vars = [600000, 0.02,0.4]` as the starting point.

Comment: @wtw It does indeed, strange... I thought leastsq was not supposed be that sensitive to the initial guesses?

Comment: Sorry - leastsq does local minimisation. There is clearly a ridge between the two starting points. So, you should get the same answer for any starting point on either side of the ridge. Does this make sense? I can try and word it better, but the key concept is local minimisation vs global minimisation.

Comment: I think I understand more or less! Thanks a lot!